# Text on pic I copied to email, reversed when I reduced size

Tags: google-chrome, email, microsoft-outlook

[Win10; Outlook 2016; Google Chrome]

Text engraved on pic I copied to email body, became reversed (only the text not the pic) when I reduced its size....I was told to flip over the pic but this will show the pic itself reversed. Not good.  Isn't it strange that only the words engraved on the pic should be reversed?

Is there a solution to this?  Thanks for any help!  :)

Comment: Are you absolutely sure the picture is not reversed? You can reverse a pasted picture by accident in Outlook when you are using the resize handles, but if the text is in the picture then the whole picture is getting reversed. You can't just reverse part of it. Please add a screen grab showing the problem.

Answer (score 0):

As michael mentioned above,usually, if the text is in the picture then the whole picture is getting reversed. You can't just change part of it.